# Moving entire row based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am rather new and fresh to VBA and I have had a look and cannot seem to find the answer I need anywhere (if I have been looking correctly).

It is a simple question but I would like to find out the best possible way to achieve it.

I have a huge amount of data around 26,000 Rows. I know the code in needing to find the data and move the row based on the results but what I would like to know is the best (Most functional) way in going through each cell in a column to find the correct criteria and move the Row.

Would it be a simple For each cell loop or something a little different that a new person (Like myself) may not know yet? if someone could tell me a good method or point me in the right direction that would be great :).

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52724352/edit) to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?, including some sample data, and expected outcome

Comment: `Autofilter` would be a good way to go, certainly more efficient than looping. Or putting your data into an array. I reckon there must be lots online on how to optimise this.

Comment: work from bottom to top

Comment: work from bottom to top

Comment: Maybe start at the bottom and work to the top

Comment: Cybernetic.Nomad - I am currently away from my laptop at the moment but I can provide an Example in a little bit when I get back to it.

SJR - Got a good place I could try looking online as I have tried but thinking I have not been googling the right things?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, using the autofilter would probably be the best way to get the results in a large data sheet.

Being new to VBA may be hard to understand where to start, so here is a simple example.

### In this sample code I am just using Columns A to O and filtering Column A for the criteria.

[image]

Run the code, enter what you want to filter for, the result will end up in Sheet2.

```
Sub FilterExample()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, rng As Range, s As String

    Set Sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

    s = InputBox("What to find?")
    ws.Range("A2:O" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
    With Sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=s
        Set rng = .Range("A2:O" & LstRw)
        rng.Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like the exact thing I need! I'll try it tomorrow when I'm on my laptop! Thank you very much!.